# Fragment cache being rewritten on changing Views in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I had implemented a fragment_cache. The cache works fine as long as we remain in the view ( say A ) which has fragment we have cached. But once I switch to another view and come back to view A, the cache is rewritten.

Also, I found from Rails.log that there was no Expire fragment log statement in it. So, I wondered why the cache is being rewritten when I switch the views, if it doesn’t expire on leaving the view containing the fragment cached.

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: how you define it? I think you have bind with action, that's why it is expiring

Comment: Some code (of the controller and the view at least) would help alot here.

Comment: I have the same issue.  with perform_Caching = true / rails dev:cache / file tmp/caching-dev.test present.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true` in your environment.
It could be possible you are testing in development mode with caching turned off.